# PHP installation on windows

Tags: php

I want to install php in my system.For this
I have downloaded the php-5.3.5.tar.bz2 (zip file).
Now from this installation help link 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.installer.msi.php
It is saying "Run the MSI installer and follow the instructions provided by the installation wizard. "

But i am not getting from where I can get MSI installer?

Comment: easy way: use wamp http://www.wampserver.com/en/ or xampp http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html or etc.

Comment: @Efazati, This is a PHP question. Don't overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello bro try this link. you dont need to install others. Just install wamp server and you will be having php,mysql and apache in your server. [Download Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: What if you already have Apache and MySQL installed? How do you simply install PHP?

Answer (score 29):

First: go to www.php.net and click on downloads, or go directly to 
<del>http://www.php.net/downloads.php</del>
http://windows.php.net/download
Choose the latest PHP x.y.z (Current stable) 
For IIS, download the **non**-threadsafe zip file

2. Extract the downloaded zip file to c:\PHP
3. Download PHP-Manager for IIS 7 (that's an IIS-controlpanel-extension, also works for IIS 8)
   from https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases‎ (make sure you choose the right bitness (32 vs. 64)
4. Open the IIS management console (inetmgr.exe)
5. Double-click PHP-Manager and click on "register new PHP installation"
   (**note to self:** never remove the PHP directory, otherwise "rien ne va plus")
   [image]
6. Choose php-cgi.exe and click ok
   [image]
7. Click on "Configure error reporting". Check "Development machine" and click apply, then click "back to main page"
   [image]
8. Go to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and create a new textfile called "phpinfo" and put this content into it :

`<?php 
    phpinfo();     // Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
    ?>`

[image]
Create a new file called hello.php in c:\inetpub\wwroot with this content 
 
`<?php echo "Hello World !" ; ?>`

[image]
10. open cmd.exe and execute "iisreset"

11. Use your browser of choice, and navigate to those pages:
    `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`
    `http://localhost/helloworld.php`

Now IIS is (should be) serving PHP.

Comment: Fantastic description of what needs to be done to get PHP running on iis, the php manual still points at an MSI file but there's not one available on the download page.

Comment: Immaculate guide to getting php running on windows. This post should be on the front page of http://windows.php.net/. Nice work!

Comment: Excellent!  I didn't realize it, but the PHP Manager was installed already on my Windows Server 2012 by the Web Platform Installer when I chose to install PHP.  However this guide showed me how to upgrade to the most recent version.

Comment: Very helpful, but a couple of steps didn't work for me in Windows 10. You could skip the first two steps. Step 3 (install PHP manager) wouldn't work and the workaround was [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/php-manager-for-iis-on-windows-10/33ef32f0-6a86-4803-abc1-6de81110f9a8?auth=1). Then go to [php.iis.net](http://php.iis.net/), click Install PHP Now & follow the instructions. Then continue this post from step 4, except that php-cgi-exe is now already installed in a different location. There is no need to reset IIS either.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see there are no MSI installers for **PHP 5.4.x** available from http://windows.php.net/

Additionally, since **PHP 5.3** there are no MSI installers available that work together with the binaries from apache.org and you have to use the binaries from http://www.apachelounge.com/

Answer (score 2):

[windows.php.net/download/](http://windows.php.net/download/).

Read the sidebar there to determine which one you should download. The MSI versions are the ones labelled "Installer".

Comment: there is nothing labeled "installer" on that page :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this direct link: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/

You will find some old msi distributions...

---

*** Files now moved to http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Answer (score 1):

MSI is a standard component of Windows. Download the MSI file, then just double click on that file and it will automatically run and install PHP.

Comment: Would be fine, except that there is no MSI file.

Comment: The original question is asking about the MSI file and how to run it: while there may no longer be an MSI download, that doesn't invalidate the answers explaining what an MSI file actually is

Answer (score 1):

To begin working with PHP you must first have access to either of the following:

> A web hosting account that supports the use of PHP web pages and grants you access to MySQL databases. If you do not have a host, but are interested in signing up for one.
>
> Have PHP and MySQL installed on your own computer. Read this lesson thorougly for more information on installing PHP.

Although MySQL is not absolutely necessary to use PHP, MySQL and PHP are wonderful complements to one another and some topics covered in this tutorial will require that you have MySQL access.
http://tutorialsbox.net/php-installation/

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here but according to the readme (install.txt) that comes with php 5.5:

> There are several all-in-one installers over the Internet, but none of
>   those are endorsed by PHP.net, as we believe that the manual
>   installation is the best choice to have your system secure and
>   optimised.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0
At the time i post this (01.2016) it's up-to-Date.

https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for installing PHP on Windows from the msi file are located at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.installer.msi.php which should help you to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I am using the same link.. i am not getting the MSI installer ?