# How to run php files on my computer

Tags: php, apache

Could anyone please tell me how to run a php file locally on my system.
Currently I am using a server to run files.
I know both php & Apache to be installed.
I need to see out put of this program, for example:

```
<?php 
$a=5;
$b=10;
$c=$a+$b;
print $c;
?>
```

Can you please tell how I can run these files of if I need anything more.

Comment: is the file `.php`. Did you put the files in the htdocs directory of apache? How do you access the file, through `http://localhost/yourscript.php`?

Comment: Do you want to run the script on a local Apache server on your computer? Or you prefer to run the script without a web server (i.e. outside a browser, like a normal executable program)? Is your computer a Windows or a Linux machine?

Comment: Install just php and in command line : `php -f path/to/file.php`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP installation on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153042/php-installation-on-windows)

Comment: May be worth your time to look in to [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (If you're running windows) or [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) for *nix

Comment: @logan: What is your operating system? On the basis of your question's content I suppose it is Windows. Am I right?

Comment: @ Topener,
i placed sample.php in htdocs, then tried http://localhost/sample.php but it only shows code of php file.

Comment: @piotrekkr, Isn't `-f` optional?

Comment: @piotrekkr , obviously.. Its Unix command .. -f indicates force..

Comment: @logan It's not `force`, more `file to read and execute` ( `man php` tells `-f file        Parse and execute file`) and yes it is optional.

Comment: This [run php on windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUwRinHHTCo) (localhost) video is pretty much the best tutorial for that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to run a web server (e.g. Apache) and browse to your localhost, mostly likely on port 80.

What you really ought to do is install an all-in-one package like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), it bundles Apache, MySQL PHP, and Perl (if you were so inclined) as well as a few other tools that work with Apache and MySQL - plus it's cross platform (that's what the 'X' in 'XAMPP' stands for).

Once you install XAMPP (and there is an installer, so it shouldn't be hard) open up the control panel for XAMPP and then click the "Start" button next to Apache - note that on applications that require a database, you'll also need to start MySQL (and you'll be able to interface with it through phpMyAdmin). Once you've started Apache, you can browse to http://localhost.

Again, regardless of whether or not you choose XAMPP (which I would recommend), you should just have to start Apache.

Comment: @Bhaxy, Is XAMPP portable?

Answer (score 81):

php have a easy way to run a light server:
first cd into php file directory, then

```js
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000
```

then you can run php

Comment: installed php with `sudo apt install php7.2-cli` on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: for what it is worth, unless your file is named `index.php` you will have to add the file path to the URL (i.e. `http://localhost:8000/MyFile.php`)

Answer (score 42):

**In short:**

1. Install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
2. Put this file to C:\wamp\www\ProjectName\filename.php
3. Go to browser: http://localhost/ProjectName/filename.php

Answer (score 11):

I just put the content in the question in a file called `test.php` and ran `php test.php`.
(In the folder where the `test.php` is.)

```
$ php foo.php                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
15
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have apache running, put your file in server folder for html files and then call it from web-browser (Like http://localhost/myfile.php ).

Comment: it is not working.
Apache is running & i placed my sample.php in htdocs
then tried, http://localhost/sample.php but it shows only code.

Answer (score 0):

**Running PHP script directly in browser:**

Here are all steps (in short) to run PHP program in XAMPP

**Step 1:** First of all, open the Apache Friends website, The download and install XAMPP for Windows.

**Step 2:** Open the XAMPP Program Control Panel and start “Apache Web Server”.
(NB: If your PHP scripts need `MySQL` database to work, Start “MySQL” service as well)

**Step 3:** Create a new folder inside “htdocs” folder. For example: “php-project”

> Path looks like: C:/xampp/htdocs/php-project/

**Step 4:** Open any text editor and create a new file and write a simple PHP program then Save it with .php extension as “example.php”.

> Path looks like: C:/xampp/htdocs/php-project/example.php

```
<?php
echo “Hello Level 5 Developers”;
?>
```

**Step 5:** Go to the browser and type “localhost/php-project/example.php” in the address bar and press enter then it gets executed.

**Step 6:** After that, you can see the output of your first PHP program like this:

> Hello Level 5 Developers

Answer (score -1):

3 easy steps to run your PHP program is:

1. The easiest way is to install [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)!
2. Do a 2-minute setup of MAMP.
3. Open the localhost server in your browser at the created port to see your program up and runing!