# Using ajax with my contact form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, forms

screenshot of error

[image]

Hey i'm trying to build a contact form for my contact page. I can't seem to get the form to send me an email of the inputs from the form when the "Submit Form" button is pressed.

...This is my html

```
<form class="send-with-ajax" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="three columns alpha">
                    <label for="first_name">First Name    <span>required</span></label>                
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name <span>required</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="seven columns omega">
                    <input type="text" required placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" name="name">
                    <input type="text" required placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" name="name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="three columns alpha">
                    <label for="email">Your Email <span>email required</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="seven columns omega">   
                    <input type="email" required placeholder="your@email" id="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">           
                <div class="three columns alpha">
                    <label for="comments">Message</label>
                </div>
                <div class="seven columns omega">   
                    <textarea placeholder="Enter you message, and please include your artist name. you can put either or choose between Pervis or Duijuan" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="seven columns offset-by-three">
                <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
                <div class="ajax-response"></div>
            </div>
</form>
```

...This is my javascript

```
$("form.send_form_email").submit(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this),
    validationErrors = false;

$('.form-error-msg').remove();

form.find("input[type='email'], input[required]").each(function(index){
        var inputValue = $(this).val(),
            inputRequired = $(this).attr('required'),
            inputType = $(this).attr('type');

$(this).removeClass('form-error');
        if(inputRequired && inputValue == '') {

$(this).after('<div class="form-error-msg">Please fill out this field.</div>');

$(this).addClass('form-error');
            validationErrors = true;
        } else if(inputType == 'email' && !isValidEmail(inputValue)) {

$(this).after('<div class="form-error-msg">Please enter an email address.</div>');
            $(this).addClass('form-error');
            validationErrors = true;
        }
    });

if (!validationErrors) {
        form.find('button:submit, input:submit').html('Sending...');
        form.find('.ajax-response').empty();
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
            function(data) {
                if (data.bFormSent) {
                    form.find('.ajax-response').empty().html(data.aResults[0]);
                    form.find('button:submit, input:submit').html('Submit Form');
                    form.find('#email, #first_name, #last_name #comments').val('');
                } else {
                    form.find('.ajax-response').empty().wrapInner('<div class="form-error-msg"></div>');
                    form.find('.ajax-response div').html(data.aErrors[0]);
                    form.find('button:submit, input:submit').html('Try Again');
                }
            }, 'json');
    }
});
```

...This is my PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

$email_to = "myemail";

$email_subject = "this subject";

function died($error) {

    // your error code can go here

    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

    echo $error."<br /><br />";

    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

    die();

}

// validation expected data exists

if(!isset($_POST['first_name' ]) ||

    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

    !isset($_POST['email']) ||

    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

 $error_message = "";

$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

if(!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {

$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be   valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 

died($error_message);
} 

$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {

  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

Comment: Why have you used `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);` The `@` suppresses everything.

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. Whats not working. What is. Are you getting any error messages.

Comment: @Steve i'm not receiving emails from the form when i submit the form.

Comment: @PraveenKumar that was an idea given to me from a friend. so you suggest i remove the "@" sign? or what do you think i should do.

Comment: But everything else works - you see success/fail messages etc? If so then this isnt really a programming question - its an issue with your mailserver. For a start remove the error suppression as noted above, and check you spam for the emails

Comment: Yes, remove the `@` and see if you have any errors...

Comment: <form class="send-with-ajax" method="post" action="send_form_email.php"> my action is set to my PHP file, whenever i click on the <b>Submit Form</b> button, i'm directed to my php file and the codes are display on the screen. thats that error im getting. I've removed the sign as mentioned above. @PraveenKumar

Comment: @PervisG Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: @Steve the codes from my PHP file are display on the screen.

Comment: @PraveenKumar sure. the screenshot is now in my post called "screenshot of error"

Comment: Looks like you haven't closed the `if` there.

Comment: @PraveenKumar code still displaying. but thanks for your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: doesn't look like PHP's being parsed here, from the screenshot. How are you using this, from a hosted site? Your own PC? if local machine, how? as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `c:///file.xxx`? Is webserver/PHP installed?

Comment: Ah man... You are not executing this using a Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah man! Just now I saw your screenshot. You are **not** executing the PHP file using a server! You need to run it using Apache / PHP Server.

**[How to run php files on my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580273/how-to-run-php-files-on-my-computer)**

> You have to run a web server (e.g. Apache) and browse to your
>   localhost, mostly likely on port 80.
>
> What you really ought to do is install an all-in-one package like
>   [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), it bundles Apache, MySQL PHP, and Perl (if you were so
>   inclined) as well as a few other tools that work with Apache and MySQL
>   - plus it's cross platform (that's what the 'X' in 'XAMPP' stands for).
>
> Once you install XAMPP (and there is an installer, so it shouldn't be
>   hard) open up the control panel for XAMPP and then click the "Start"
>   button next to Apache - note that on applications that require a
>   database, you'll also need to start MySQL (and you'll be able to
>   interface with it through phpMyAdmin). Once you've started Apache, you
>   can browse to http://localhost.
>
> Again, regardless of whether or not you choose XAMPP (which I would
>   recommend), you should just have to start Apache.

**Another one**

> **In short:**
>
> 1. Install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
> 2. Put this file to C:\wamp\www\ProjectName\filename.php
> 3. Go to browser: http://localhost/ProjectName/filename.php

Comment: what was changed? for OP/future visitors and myself ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Omg! Sorry, I made this mistake. I will write it. I have commented it. See above for the question.

Comment: See [my comment to the OP...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956000/using-ajax-with-my-contact-form#comment55672008_33956000)

Comment: @PraveenKumar ah I thought that was my problem, but i also thought i was going to be able to have it work with out a server. BTW im a newbie, i only know a few about code that's why i trying to learn. Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: @PraveenKumar so to go over what u said. I need a host, and a domain to run Apache right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the help too.

Comment: @PervisG you're welcome.