# Simple website won't open image on desktop using __DIR__

Tags: php, html, web, directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is Hello World page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <img src= "<?php echo __DIR__ .'/pic.png' ?>"> 
</body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out why the code isn't showing the image. I made sure to name the file with a `.php` extension and to put both files in the same folder (the desktop).

The eventual goal is to upload an entire folder to a server. Within that folder, there will be an `index.php` file and an image. How can I point the file to the image?

Comment: in the browser select "view source" see what that shows. if the pic isin the same folder, you dont need a path at all

Comment: Are you running it as http:// or file://?  You can't use file://

Comment: It shows the same code, even with the php code.

Comment: Do you have a web server like Apache running?

Comment: You're not using echo #justsaying

Comment: @user2182349 that's what I'm trying to avoid. I am trying to migrate from using file://C:/.... to `__DIR__`

Comment: You can't use file://

Comment: If you want to work with PHP, you can use a stack like XAMPP or bitnami

Comment: @ChinLeung added echo, still doesn't work.

Comment: @user2182349 I want to basically upload a folder to a server. Within that folder is a `index.php` file. This file needs to find an image within the same folder. How do I do this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can't put the image tag in the head. Move it inside your body tag.

Comment: @ChinLeung ok I moved it, but the broken image symbol is now simply beneath the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run php files on my computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580273/how-to-run-php-files-on-my-computer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **pic.png** is in the same directory, this will work.

```
<img src="pic.png">
```

Also, move the *img* tag into the *body*.

Comment: This worked on my laptop, but not on the actual server.

Comment: Did you upload **pic.png**?

Comment: Yes. Both files are there.

Comment: Can you see the page, without the image?

Comment: Yup! But there is a broken image symbol

Comment: Is the file name the same case?  If you're on a Linux server, **pic.png** must be **pic.png**, it can't be **pic.PNG** or **Pic.png**.